# How can I distinguish between a PhoneGap app and a native browser?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

To speed up development, our team has gotten into the habit of testing most of our phonegap implementation directly in Chrome (since it's almost all Javascript). But there's certain code that we want to run in the ondeviceready callback that Phonegap provides (or just on document.ready in the browser). How can we distinguish between the two situations if we want to call different code in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're following the same approach and had the same problem. Here's how we solved it for Android (should work with WebKit browsers i.e. on iOS as well).

The idea is:

- Create a Java class which says that PhoneGap is active.
- Add it to the list of global objects in the browser.
- Write a JavaScript wrapper which encapsulates the check.

Now some code.

Java class:

```
public class MyPhoneGap {

    public boolean isActive() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Registering an instance of this class with a browser:

```
public class MyActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        this.appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyPhoneGap(), "MyPhoneGap");
    }
}
```

JavaScript wrapper:

```
My.PhoneGap = {
    active : null,
    isActive : function() {
        if (!My.Util.Type.isBoolean(My.PhoneGap.active)) {
            if (My.Util.Type.exists(window.MyPhoneGap)) {
                if (window.MyPhoneGap.isActive()) {
                    My.PhoneGap.active = true;
                } else {
                    My.PhoneGap.active = false;
                }
            } else {
                My.PhoneGap.active = false;
            }
        }
        return My.PhoneGap.active;
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
if (My.PhoneGap.isActive()) {
    // Rely on PhoneGap APIs
} else {
    // Use some mock/default/dummy impl
}
```

One last thing: developing/testing in Chrome is very convenient, but please do test on the real device. Differences in performance/API reliability are tremendously different.

Comment: And out of curiosity, is there any reason you used addJavascriptInterface instead of a PhoneGap plugin?

Comment: @WaynnLue PhoneGap plugins are asynchronous, this makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if device is undefined in JavaScript

```
/* are we running on device or in a browser? */                                                                                              
this.isDevice = (typeof(device) != 'undefined');

/* if the device is not defined we assume we in a browser */
if(!this.isDevice) {
    ... browser code here ...
}
```